# Nginx reverse proxy to Jetty app server via Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, nginx-location, jetty-9, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a website that uses Cloudflare to protect and proxy the site.

I am using a Cloudflare SSL certificate on my origin nginx webserver so that all requests are dealt with via HTTPS and this works as needed.

I have set up a Node.js server and a Jetty based application server running Xwiki on the same physical server as is hosting my Nginx webserver.

I set up nginx reverse proxing via my nginx.conf file so that nginx points to the respective 'application' server when the corresponding URL is requested e.g.

```
https://SITE-ROOT/node
```

This reverse proxies to my node.js server running on port 3001 on the localhost using the below location settings in my nginx.conf file...

```
location /node {
            proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.69:3001;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }
```

This works as needed and the node.js page is served via HTTPS via my sites pubic URL and via CloudFlares service.

When I try to do that same for the Xwiki site which runs on the Jetty (Java) application server on the localhost on port 8080, e.g.

```
https://SITE-ROOT/xwiki

location /xwiki/ {
            proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.69:8080/xwiki;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }
```

I get the below error:

```
DNS points to prohibited IP

Unfortunately, it is resolving to an IP address that 
is creating a conflict within Cloudflare's system.
```

I do not understand why this is happening as I would expect the same thing to happen with the node reverse proxy request.

The only difference I can think of is that Xwiki is running within the Jetty application server on the same host as the nginx and node services and this means that nginx and Jetty aren't/can't handshake in the same way nginx and node can when it comes to reverse proxing...

If I put my sites real IP address and the Xwiki port number in the proxy redirect section of my nginx.conf file, e.g.

```
https://SITE-ROOT/xwiki

location /xwiki/ {
            proxy_pass         http://EXTERNAL-REAL-IP:8080/xwiki;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }
```

This works in as much as the Xwiki default page loads but the URL changes to the real external IP of my server and does not use SSL. I understand that this is because the Jetty server is serving the page via port 8080 and by passing nginx altogether.

So my actual question is, how can I get the Jetty based Xwiki service to load on a location within my Cloudflare proxied website using Nginx reverse proxy or can you help me understand where I am going wrong with this...

I suspect I need to install the SSL certificate that is installed on my nginx server on the Jetty server also so that nginx see's the Jetty server as local resource - but I am very uncertain on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my original question, I was expecting the xwiki redirect/proxy to work in the same way as the node redirect has worked...

I was scratching my head and wondering why this wasnt working so I had a play...

I found that there may have been a problem with they way I was forwarding the request so I removed the below line

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
```

and replaced it with:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

so that Nginx would take care of the SSL site of things

```
location /test {
            proxy_pass              EXTERNAL-REAL-IP:8080/;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                        }
```

I created a new 'test' location in my nginx config file as per the above and pointed it to the external IP and 8080 port that Jetty is running on... and boom, I got a Jetty error page on my `https://SITE-NAME/test` `url saying that the 'test' location wasn't found, meaning that the nginx reverse proxy was working as needed...

Although I may not have needed to do this if I had of renamed to the location setting in the nginx.conf file, I found from reading the Jetty documentation that I could change the URL the war based application would run on Jetty by renaming the war file in webapp directory of Jetty home.

I changed the war file name from xwiki to test and restarted Jetty and loaded my `https://SITE-NAME/test` in my browser...

Hey-presto, my site was now serving the proxied Xwiki application from Jetty via nginx using HTTPS on my `https://SITE-NAME/test` url...

I have changed the name of the war file and location in the nginx file to point to something like `https://SITE-NAME/test` and it works like a charm!

I then changed the `https://EXTERNAL-REAL-IP/test` location in nginx.conf to use the nginx LAN IP so that Nginx would proxy locally and this still worked as needed - so, all in all, happy days...